# Resource.id dosent have a definition xamarin err

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a problem with my program because after changing the name of the project by the name I was asked to give it, I had an error that does not allow me to compile it due to the lack of the object it refers to.
I try cleaning and building again but dosen't work
[image: err][image]

Comment: Please close your VS, then open your project folder, find `bin` and `obj` folders, delete all of them, re-open and rebuild your project. If this issue is still existed.

Comment: the issue still

Comment: Please open your project folder. Open `xxxprojectName\Resources` folder, copy the `Resource.designer.cs` file to other places. Then open your project by VS, delete the `Resource.designer.cs` file, rebuild your project(This `Resource.designer.cs` file will be re-generated).In the end, add this `Resource.designer.cs` file by adding existing item like this url. https://imgur.com/a/WC6TNHr, re-deploy your project.